# How can i add a customized footer layout in a activity layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello Community i am new and need your expert opinions.
i have custom footer.xml layout with some buttons on it , i want to add this xml to my activity layout, and i also want to implement click listner for button. Need your guidance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipSwe.png)

i am able to include footer through

```
  <include layout="@layout/footer" />
```

it includes the footer layout in activity layout, but there are some buttons i also want to implement action for them.is there any way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this on your button definition (inside the footer layout)

```
 android:onclick="clickMethodName"
```

Just ensure that any class that uses that layout implements 'clickMethodName'.

Alternatively, you can set the onClickListener in your class, after finding the button by id.

See the official documentation for more details and examples, right at the top:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Comment: yes it solved the problem, but not in the way i want.